# How to plot data in Latex with a two level x axis

Tags: diagrams, plot, bar-chart

I want to create a plot for a latex document based upon data like this

```
1 1 11.5
1 2 11.2
2 1 11.0
2 2 10.8
2 3 10.5
3 1 9.5
3 2 9.1
3 3 9.05
3 4 9.0
4 1 8.95
4 2 8.9
```

The first two columns should determine the x axis and the third column is the data for the y axis.

Edit: To clarify here is some more background information on the data:

> The data above is of course meaningless. The format however is not. I am running a nested multigrid iteration for an eigenvalue-problem. Basicly I am solving the same problem numericaly on multiple levels, each new level beeing more precise than the one before. You start by solving the problem on a coarse level. That solution is taken as start value on the next (finer) level and so on. So the first column is the level number, the second column is the number of the iteration step on that level and the third column is the approximated value from that step.

In the end the plot should look like this:

[image: plot]

I created this plot with mathcha.io, but unfortunately the export functions on that site do not support this plot to be exported for latex. Is there a good way to get such a plot in a Latex document?

I am thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. // Obviously the x-axis does not indicate continuous data: it looks more like classified data w.r.t. x. Strange. // So, in your example you show 11 data points; just enumerate the rows from 1 to 11 and discard (or ignore) the first two coulmns. Then, fiddle around with some "axis"-mimick. Sorry, this data presentation does not make much sense to me. / What do you intend to show? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the Greeting. // The data above is of course meaningless. The format however is not. I am running a nested multigrid iteration for an eigenvalue-problem. Basicly I am solving the same problem numericaly on multiple levels, each level beeing more precise. You start by solving the problem on a coarse level. That solution is taken as start value on the next level. So the first column is the level number, the second column is the number of the iteration step on that level and the third column is the approximated value from that step.

Comment: To your suggestion: Yes that is of course the "emergency"-way of doing it. But I wish that there is another way of "automaticly" doing it just by providing the data. Because the number of iteration steps on each level for example is not the same on every run, due to different parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I suggest to include the background information in your question, so people can understand right away. // Well, the main tasks again seems to be to draw a "fancy" axis, i.e. one which shows your "run - iteration" pairs ... // To widen the scope, viewed from this perspective it is not much different to drawing a bar-chart with labeled bars. // So may be skimming through the tags [bar-chart] provides a solution for you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bar-chart